# How to remove event listener in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code that is supposed to add event listener on a parent component when element is clicked and remove it when the mouse is up but the removing of event listener is not working.

```
      const move = (e)=>{
 setPosition({top:e.clientY-50,left:e.clientX-65})

}

const handleMouseDown = (e) =>{
    backgroundRef.current.addEventListener('mousemove',(e)=>move(e))
}

const handleMouseUp = (e) =>{
    backgroundRef.current.removeEventListener('mousemove',(e)=>move(e))
}

return <div ref={iconRef} onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp} style={position} className='icon-container' >
    <img draggable='false' src={image} alt=''/>
    <p>{text}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe take a look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: Why do you add event listeners like this in react? Also, to use `removeEventListener` you have to pass the same function reference, creating a new function won't work. `(e)=>move(e)` creates a new function

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the same function reference to both addEventListener and removeEventListener. You are currently passing a new anonymous function on each call.

```
const move = (e)=>{
 setPosition({top:e.clientY-50,left:e.clientX-65})

}

const handleMouseDown = (e) =>{
    backgroundRef.current.addEventListener('mousemove',move) // passing the same reference 
}

const handleMouseUp = (e) =>{
    backgroundRef.current.removeEventListener('mousemove',move) // passing the same reference 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for `removeEventListener` to work in this case, in addition to passing the reference equal `move` for it, the functions might also need to be saved by `useCallback`. Because when state `position` changes and the component re-renders, `handleMouseUp` could be recreated with a new copy of `move` already.

Example with reference equal `move` and `useCallback`:

```js
const Child = ({ image, text, backgroundRef }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(null);

  const move = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setPosition({
      top: `${e.clientY - 50}px`,
      left: `${e.clientX - 65}px`,
    });
  }, []);

  const handleMouseDown = React.useCallback(() => {
    backgroundRef.current.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
  }, [move]);

  const handleMouseUp = React.useCallback(() => {
    backgroundRef.current.removeEventListener('mousemove', move);
  }, [move]);

  return (
    <div
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      style={position}
      className="icon-container"
    >
      <img draggable="false" src={image} alt="" />
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const backgroundRef = React.useRef(null);
  return (
    <section ref={backgroundRef}>
      <Child
        text=" Drag this"
        image="https://picsum.photos/100"
        backgroundRef={backgroundRef}
      />
    </section>
  );
};


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-container > * {
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But **alternatively**, if the goal is to make the component follow the mouse move, it might not be necessary to host the event from the parent. The component could keep a `active` state to be toggled by clicks, which controls whether the dragging is active.

`useCallback`, `addEventListener`, and a `ref` from the parent can be omitted with this optional approach.

Example with `active` state:

```js
const Child = ({ image, text }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(null);

  const move = (e) => {
    if (!active) return;
    setPosition({
      top: `${e.clientY - 50}px`,
      left: `${e.clientX - 65}px`,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div
      onMouseDown={() => setActive(true)}
      onMouseUp={() => setActive(false)}
      style={position}
      className="icon-container"
      onMouseMove={active ? move : null}
    >
      <img draggable="false" src={image} alt="" />
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <section>
      <Child text=" Drag this" image="https://picsum.photos/100" />
    </section>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-container > * {
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```